# Linux Git remote to windows server 2016

Tags: git, git-remote, git-config

I am facing an issue when doing on Linux Ubuntu

```
git init
git remote add origin username@domain@server_IP:e:/myRepo
git fetch origin
```

After entering my password, I have this message:

```
fatal: ''e:/myRepo'' does not appear to be a git repository    
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.    
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I searched and found people with the "same issue", but the reason I am posting this question is that I went through the proposed solutions and none of them worked for me.

Here is my situation:

-bare repository on windows server 2016 running OpenSSH. (e:\myRepo with full rights for everyone)

-was able to do the operation from Windows10 PCs by using powershell to run additional git commands

```
git init
git remote add origin username@domain@server_IP:e:/myRepo
git config --local remote.origin.uploadpack "powershell git-upload-pack"
git config --local remote.origin.receivepack "powershell git-receive-pack"
git fetch origin
```

Thanks.

Comment: and do you have *the correct access rights*? There is literally nothing anyone can do if you don't have permission to clone the repo

Comment: yes @Liam
for tests purpose, I granted everyone full control.

Comment: That error message seems to suggest otherwise. What is your repo hosted on? how did you grant "full control to everyone"?

Comment: Wait, is this windows or Linux?

Comment: the bare repo is on windows and the local is on linux

Comment: I actually have the same message on windows until I type in the git configs commands


git config --local remote.origin.uploadpack "powershell git-upload-pack"

git config --local remote.origin.receivepack "powershell git-receive-pack"

Answer (score 1):

Your *workaround settings*

```
git config --local remote.origin.uploadpack "powershell git-upload-pack"
git config --local remote.origin.receivepack "powershell git-receive-pack"
```

are in the [Git For Windows wiki](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-Win32_OpenSSH#on-client)

## Answer

You have to apply those workaround fixes on all your git clients (`Windows`, `*nix`), so long as the Git Server is `Windows`.

## Explanation

Those double-quotes in error message's path (E.g.  `''C:\some\path''`) are related to the Git Server's default shell (i.e. Command Prompt, since it's OS is Windows) not parsing paths correctly, before passing them to `git-upload-pack` and `git-receive-pack`.

You get similar error messagesfor `git clone` (as in the stated link), `git push`, `git remote -v`, and in your case, `git fetch`.

#### Example of an error

```
$ git remote -v
origin git@windowshost:C:/some.git/
$ git push origin
fatal: ''C:/some.git/'' does not appear to be a git repository
```